# Outlook - Is it possible to apply custom views to folders in different pst files?

Tags: vba, outlook, vsto

I have a IMAP account and would like to copy custom views across to other folders in different pst files.

The idea is to use VBA to do that.

At the moment I can use VBA to apply a specific view to the IMAP folder because I already created these views. But, looking in other pst files, these same views don't exist there.

Based on the tip of using the `Outlook.View` I created a form with 2 buttons and with 2 events that call 2 different subs with a store/apply functions:

```
Private Sub CommandButtonApplyView_Click()
    Call ApplyStoredView
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButtonStoreView_Click()
    Call StoreView
End Sub
```

And on a module I have:

```
Public StoredView As Outlook.View

Public Sub StoreView()
    Set StoredView = Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentView
End Sub


Public Sub ApplyStoredView()
    StoredView.Apply
End Sub
```

The idea is to store the view on the global var `StoredView` and store it on click using `CommandButtonApplyView` and on any other folder using the other button `CommandButtonStoreView`

The folder where my view is to be applied (e.g. in another pst file) does not re-format according with the view that was stored.

It seems that we only keep the standard 4 views existing in the pst "Table view", "Compact", "Single" and "Preview". The new view (stored) isn't considered.

Answer (score 0):

You can read`MAPIFolder.CurrentView.XML` and apply it to another folder.

Comment: I assume the folder can be at any pst file open. Is this right?

Comment: I was trying to store the view in a global var (using a windows form app) and then apply it to any folder but the code fails: Public StoreView As Outlook.View gives the error "Expected function or variable"

Comment: The idea is to have a windows form in the simplest way possible: two buttons. each one to call the subs for `StoreView()` and `ApplyStoredView()` using a public var `StoreView `: `Public StoreView As Outlook.View

Public Sub StoreView()
    Set StoreView = Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentView
End Sub

Public Sub ApplyStoredView()
    StoreView.Apply
End Sub`

Comment: Click one button -> store, go and select another folder and click the other button to apply view. At the moment, this is causing an error: "Expected function or variable".

Comment: Do you have the "dim" keyword?

Comment: I'm setting the var as public: `Public StoreView As Outlook.View`

Comment: I don't need it, right? I'm defining it at a module level. But I need to store it while the form is loaded and pick it to apply when I need it.

Comment: can you help? I'd really like to understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Please update your original post to show your latest code that you are having problems with.

Comment: I have no problem running that script from Outlook VBA